# WCF Service use FTP as transport

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, ftp

Bit of an edge question, but here goes.

I'm looking at ways of writing a WCF service that is accessed using the FTP protocol. The system where the client will be running has **only** got access to FTP via port 21 - all other traffic is blocked, and non-FTP traffic through port 21 gets filtered out aswell (tried running a RESTful service through port 21 with no luck). I have read that SOAP can be used over various protocols (HTTP, FTP, SMTP etc.). I have the service working fine with a HTTP binding on various ports, but am stuck at the point of binding it to FTP. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: What happened to "open port or no app for you"?

Comment: Hahaha, I wish it were that simple, I really do. There are a host of proxies and firewalls insulating the inner from the outer, so it's a bit too-hard-basket I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

> As an example of a gateway from SOAP into another environment, one can imagine a SOAP to FTP gateway where FTP commands are mapped into a SOAP message. In order to actually talk to the FTP server the calls will have to be expressed in a language understandable by FTP rather than in SOAP.

```
<?php 
$myLogin = 'foo';
$myPass = 'bar';

$env = '<S:Envelope
   xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Header>
      <m:path xmlns:m="http://www.soap.org/path">
         <m:action>http://www.im.org/chat</m:action>
         <m:to>soap://D.com/some/endpoint</m:to>
         <m:forward>
            <m:via>soap://B.com</m:via>
            <m:via>soap://C.com</m:via>
         </m:forwawd>
         <m:reverse>
            <m:via/>
         </m:reverse>
         <m:from>mailto:frystyk@microsoft.com</m:from>
         <m:id>uuid:84b9f5d0-33fb-4a81-b02b-5b760641c1d6</m:id>
      </m:path>
   </S:Header>
   <S:Body>
      ...
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>';

$socket=fsockopen('http://example.com', 21); 
$t=fgets($socket, 128); 
fwrite($socket, "USER $myLogin\r\n"); 
$t=fgets($socket, 128); 
fwrite($socket, "PASS $myPass\r\n"); 
$t=fgets($socket, 128); 
fwrite($socket, "PUTS $env\r\n"); 
fwrite($socket, "QUIT\r\n"); 
fclose($socket); 
?>
```

**References**

- [SOAP Message Path Modeling](https://www.w3.org/2001/03/WSWS-popa/paper41)
- [SMTP Transport Binding for SOAP 1.1](http://www.pocketsoap.com/specs/smtpbinding/)
- [Using curl over ftp took 3+ minutes for a 4 byte file w/ EPSV](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2011/10/using-curl-ftp-took-3-minutes-4-byte-file-epsv/)
- [PHP Manual: fwrite](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php)
- [Describing Media Content of Binary Data in XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-media-types/)
- [XML-binary Optimized Packaging](https://www.w3.org/TR/xop10/)
- [SOAP Messages with Attachments](https://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments)
- [SOAP Version 1.2 Email Binding](https://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-email)